# wirelessly connect 4 slave raspberry pi's to master raspberry pi without access to the internet

Tags: wifi, node.js, sockets

I'm working on my senior design project using Nodejs and it involves 4 slave raspberry pi's wirelessly connecting to a master raspberry pi. The master must be able to send and receive data from the 4 slaves at any time and it needs to work anywhere, even with no wifi signal. The 5 will be close to each other at all times of course.

Using Bluetooth to connect to multiple things at once seems very complicated to work with, but it might possible to have the master pi be treated as a router of sorts, and the slaves will connect to it, even though the master won't actually connect to the internet. This connection might work using Socket. However, I don't know if this is possible.

I have some experience with using socket to connect a raspberry pi to a web server, so I feel have most of this down. If someone could point me in the right direction for this router stuff that would be great, I'm sure I could figure this out once I learn the names of what I'm looking for.

Thank You

Comment: Why don't you just use a local wireless network with wifi?  It doesn't have to be connected to the network.  Connect each Pi via a wireless router.

Comment: why do you think that an internet connection is required?

Comment: @joan ... so, `it needs to work anywhere` as long as you also have a wireless router?

Comment: why not make the "master pi" a wifi access point that the other 4 pi's connect to?

Comment: @JaromandaX WiFi cannot be used because it must work "*even with no wifi signal*".

Comment: You wrote: "*The 5 will be close to each other at all times of course.*" - can you connect them wired?

Comment: @Ingo - I thought OP meant no WiFi with internet access :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I can't have them connected, they are going to be moving a lot, each of the slaves will be held by a person, and I don't want them to be restricted.

they need to work anywhere, even in the middle of the forest.

I just need a way for the pis to communicate, and using websocket seemed like a good idea since I have experience. I was told by a friend that making the master pi act as a wireless access point should be possible, they just didn't know the details on how.

Comment: so when `they need to work anywhere, even in the middle of the forest` the `5 will be close to each other at all times of course` ... so use wifi access point on the master

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you point me to tutorial for that?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=raspberry+pi+access+point